# Get current subcategory product thumb Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to get the product category thumb for a subcategory of a specific parent category on my product page - Im able to retrieve all the images for the subcategory of my given parent category - but I only want to show the image that belongs to the subcategory of the product. Now it shows all images on the product from all the parents child.

How do a set it so it only show the one subcategory im on, but still only from the given parent?

Code:

```
<?php
$catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'child_of'=>'74'));
foreach($catTerms as $catTerm) : ?>
<?php $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $catTerm->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 

// get the image URL
$image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );  ?>
<li><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="152" height="245"/><span><?php echo $catTerm->name; ?></span></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Edit: solved by doing it this way:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ){
        if ( $term->parent == '174081' )  {
        $category_name = $term->name;
        $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
         }
    }
```